# Replacing data in one table with data in another table using a unique ID

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm using Access 2016 to view data from a table on our SQL server. I have a massive audit log where the record being viewed is represented by a "FolderID" field. I have another table that has values for the FolderID (represented as "fid") along with columns identifying the record's name and other ID numbers.

I want to be able to replace the FolderID value in the first table with CUSTOMER_NAME value from the second table so I know what's being viewed at a glance.

I've tried googling different join techniques to build a query that will accomplish this, but my google-fu is weak or I'm just not caffeinated enough today.

Table 1.

```
EventTime              EventType    FolderID                
 4/4/2019 1:23:39 PM    A            12345
```

Table 2

```
fid      acc     Other_ID   Third_ID    CUSTOMER_NAME
12345     0       9875      12345678     Doe, John
```

Basically I want to query Table 2 to search for fid using the value in Table 1 for FolderID, and I want it to respond with the CUSTOMER_NAME associated with the FolderID/fid. The result would look like:

```
EventTime              EventType    FolderID                
 4/4/2019 1:23:39 PM    A           Doe, John
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query and check if it helps!.

```
Select EventTime, EventType , CUSTOMER_NAME AS FolderID  FROM Table1, Table2 Where Table1.FolderID = Table2.fid;
```

Basically, **'AS'** is doing what you want here as you can rename your column to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid because I thought I was too smart to use the freaking Query Wizard. When I did, and it prompted me to create relationships and actually think about what I was doing, it came up with this.

> SELECT [table1].EventTime, [table1].EventType, [table1].FolderID, [table1].ObjRef, [table1].AreaID, [table1].FileID, [table2].CUSTOMER_NAME, [table2].fid FROM [table2] 
>       LEFT JOIN [table1] ON [table2].[fid] = [table1].[FolderID];